# OnPostExecute(int result) not called in xamarin android

Tags: android-asynctask, xamarin.android

I have been searching from an hour, but no luck.
I am just calling the asynctask from my activity Oncreate method.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.personal_profile_detail);    

        new LoadProfileInfo(this).Execute();

    }
```

During debugging break point in OnPostExecute never get hit.

```
public class LoadProfileInfo : AsyncTask<int, int, int>
{
    Activity RootActivity;
    LinearLayout PP_Error;
    LinearLayout PP_Loading;
    LinearLayout PP_Perfect;
    bool ErrorFlag;
    ProfileDetails data;

    public LoadProfileInfo(Activity activity)
    {
        RootActivity = activity;
    }
    protected override void OnPreExecute()
    {
        base.OnPreExecute();
        PP_Error = RootActivity.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.PP_Error);
        PP_Loading = RootActivity.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.PP_Loading);
        PP_Perfect = RootActivity.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.PP_Perfect);
        PP_Loading.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        PP_Error.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        PP_Perfect.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        RootActivity.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
    }
    protected override int RunInBackground(params int[] @params)
    {
        try
        {
            PersonalProfileAccessLayer _ppal = new PersonalProfileAccessLayer();
            data = _ppal.GetPersonalDetails();
            ErrorFlag = !data.IsInternet;
            return 1;
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            string a = "";
            return 1;
        }

    }
    protected override void OnPostExecute(int result)
    {
        base.OnPostExecute(result);
        if (ErrorFlag)
        {
            PP_Loading.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            PP_Error.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            PP_Perfect.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
        else
        {
            RootActivity.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ppusername).Text = "Arslan";
            PP_Loading.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            PP_Error.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            PP_Perfect.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        RootActivity.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
    }
}
```

i have checked all the override keywords.
All of the return types.
I have also used asynctask in my fragment, but that worked fine.
is there any restriction of calling asynctask from activity..?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tested your code, it works well. I have some suggestions, try to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("OnPostExecute Start");` to make sure this method haven't be called really. Or try to replace your `RunInBackground` with `DoInBackground`,[here is Xamarin.Android document about `AsyncTask`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.AsyncTask/) 
 and [here is Android document about `AsycnTask`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.OS.AsyncTask/)